# How to use $q.all when one of the promises is needed for one last call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have to make 3 calls that, after completed will return a single object.  The first two calls are independent, however the 3rd call requires as one of the parameters one data value that is returned from one of the first two calls.  The pattern below is messed up, I'm trying to avoid making the third call in the place where I call myFunction, any ideas of how can I fix this

```
function myFunction(){
    var promise1 = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'a/pi-o-url', cache: 'true'});
    var promise2 = $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api-v-url', cache: 'true'});

   var myNewObj = {obj1:{}, obj2: {}, obj3: {}};
        $q.all([promise1, promise2])    
        //i'd like to somehow make all the calls in one single function (within myFunction and juts return a single object)
}
```

I don't want to do:

```
myFunction()
.then(function(data){
                myNewObj.obj1 = data[0];
                myNewObj.obj2 = data[1];
                myService(data[0].id).then(function(moreData){
                     myNewObj.obj3 = moreData;
                     return moreData;
            })
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what exactly you want? you have to make another call where you need resolved data of previous call?

Comment: I want to be able to call myFunction and return one object.  This object is made up with data from 3 different calls.  Two of the calls are independent and I can use $q.all, however for the 3rd call I need as a parameter a data value that si returned by one of the first two calls

Comment: well, if you have dependency on async execution, you cannot return the data directly, you have to return a promise. Otherwise you can return a reference and populate that later, see `$resource` for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
function myFunction() {
    var promise1 = $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'a/pi-o-url', cache: 'true' });
    var promise2 = $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api-v-url', cache: 'true' });

    return $q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function (data) {
        var myNewObj = {
            obj1: data[0],
            obj2: data[1]
        };

        return myService(data[0].id).then(function (moreData) {
            myNewObj.obj3 = moreData;
            return myNewObj;
        });
    }
}
```

That way, with [promise chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining), the promise from `myFunction` will be resolved with the complete object.

Comment: Promise chaining is the way to go.  For slightly more readable code, you can define the success functions and just use their names in the `.then(func)` callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the first 2 promises in parallel, then chain the 3rd promise

```
function myFunction(){
    var promise1 = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'a/pi-o-url', cache: 'true'});
    var promise2 = $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api-v-url', cache: 'true'});


    $q.all([promise1, promise2])
    .then(function([result1, result2]) {
        // after the first 2 promises resolve, create the 3rd promise
        var promise3 = $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api-v-url', cache: 'true'});

        // this will return an array with 3 promise values
        return $q.all[result1, result2, promise3];
    })
}
```